# no schema with key or ref with AJV when validating schema property

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I'm using `ajv` and I want to validate only one specific property. My schema is:

```
{
    properties:{
        dog:{type:"string"}
    }
}
```

I want to know if `foo` is a valid dog.

I do:

```
const ajv = new AjvModule.default({ removeAdditional: "all", coerceTypes: true});
ajv.addSchema(require("./schemas/the_above_schema.json"))
ajv.validate(`#/dog`, 'foo');
```

But I get the error: `Error: no schema with key or ref "#/dog"`

I also tried: `ajv.addSchema(require("./schemas/the_above_schema.json"), 'dog_schema')

and `ajv.validate(`dog_schema#/dog`, 'foo')

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer.

To validate only one specific property you can do:

```
ajv.addSchema(schema, schema_name)
const valid = ajv.validate(`${schema_name}#/properties/${property_name}`, value);
```

You can also use `definitions` instead of `properties`